# Cocos2d build error

Tags: cocos2d-x

When trying to run build_native.py command inside my proj.android folder I get the error:

.cocos-project.json is not found.

All I did was generate this new project with the cocos.py new command before I ran the build_native.py command so I don't know why this would be.  I'm doing this on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Solution which worked for me:

create a new project (with the same env,language etc.)
copy .cocos-project.json file from that new folder to the one you had problems with and it should build. It worked on my mac and windows machine.

I hope it helps.